# Скругления у вертикальных вкладок с градиентным фоном и тенью

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMGzQb)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 900px;
  width: 33%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(24, 174, 177, 0.93), #1c9f94 24%, #12ce80 54%, #107a7c 76%, #096668);
  box-shadow: 5px 0 10px 0 rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6);
}

.options-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.options-item-active,
.options-item-inactive {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 40px 50px 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.options-item-active {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 10px 1px rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6);
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 130%;
  width: 30px;
  right: -11px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 19px, #fff 20px) top left, radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, transparent 19px, #fff 20px) bottom left;
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: default;
}

.test::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 19px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 3px 10px 1px rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.test::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 19px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px -3px 10px 1px rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6);
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="options-wrapper">
    <div class="options-item-active">
      <span class="options-item-text">Item 1</span>
      <span class="test"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="options-item-inactive">
      <span class="options-item-text">Item 2</span>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

вот примерчик, нужно сделать скругления, там все видно, что требуется. Проблема, в таком решении, с тенями(именно на скруглениях), кто поможет и знает как сделать, подскажите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроме обычной тени у псевдоэлементов есть еще и белая неразмытая тень чтобы закрыть угол зеленного элемента. Тень кст тоже немного поправил. В общем, из-за ее смещения вправо на `5px` слева образовывалась "незатененная" белая область. Добавив такую же тень, но только со смещением влево эта область закрылась. У `span` также есть градиент на фоне. Он прозрачен сверху и снизу т.к. там зеленную часть закрывает белая тень псевдоэлементов, и белый по центру до куда псевоэлементам нет смысла тянуть свою белую тень.

Не супер масштабируемо, но если высота пункта не будет сильно меняться, то годится.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 900px;
  width: 33%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(24, 174, 177, 0.93), #1c9f94 24%, #12ce80 54%, #107a7c 76%, #096668);
  box-shadow: 5px 0 10px 0 rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6);
}

.options-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.options-item-active,
.options-item-inactive {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 40px 50px 50px; 
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

.options-item-active {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow:  inset 6px 0px 10px 1px rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6);
}

.options-item-active > .test {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: calc(100% + 40px);
    width: 40px;
    right: -20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 19%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 79%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%);
}

.options-item-active > .test:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    left: -20px;
    top: -20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 10px 0 rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6), -5px 0 10px 0 rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6), 0 0 0 30px white;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.options-item-active > .test:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    left: -20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 10px 0 rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6), -5px 0 10px 0 rgba(120, 150, 150, 0.6), 0 0 0 30px white;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="options-wrapper">
    <div class="options-item-active">
      <span class="options-item-text">Item 1</span>
      <span class="test"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="options-item-inactive">
      <span class="options-item-text">Item 2</span>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное